# kalman filter with redundant state measurements

Tags: orientation, kalman-filter, sensor-fusion, inertial-navigation

I am trying to implement a kalman filter for orientation detection. just like most other implementations I found online, I will be using a gyro and accelerometer to measure the pitch and roll, however I intend to also add horizon detection. This will give me a second reading for the pitch and roll. This means that I will have two means of measuring the current state, accelerometer and horizon detection whilst the gyro will be used for control.

So far I have implemented the filter on the sensor data and horizon detection separately based on this tutorial: http://blog.tkjelectronics.dk/2012/09/a-practical-approach-to-kalman-filter-and-how-to-implement-it/

Which part of the kalman filter do I have to modify for the algorithm to choose the best reading between the predicted state, accelerometer reading and horizon detected reading? Any help, links to papers or sites will be appreciated
thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 8):

The KF consists of two parallel components: 
1. the estimated state, AND
2. the uncertainty in that estimate (specifically, the covariance matrix of the state components).

When combining 2 estimates of the state, the standard method takes a weighted average, with the weights being the inverses of the (co)variances.  That is, the more certain of the 2 estimates (smaller covariance) is weighted more highly than the other.

So if you are not already tracking the covariances for your 2 estimates, you will need to do this.

For a scalar state X with 2 estimates X' and X", you would have a variance for each estimate: V' and V", with inverses C' = 1/V' and C" = 1/V".  (The "certainties" C are easier to use than the variances V.)

Then the MMSE estimate (which is what the KF attempts to optimize) of the state is given by: Xmmse = (X'/V' + X"/V") / (1/V' + 1/V").
[There is also a corresponding update to V at this point, based on V' and V".]

For vectorial states, V will be replaces by a covariance matrix, and the divisions will become matrix inverses.  In this case, it may be easier to track the inverses C directly: Xmmse = (C' + C") \ (C' * X' + C" * X") [and corresponding update to C], 
where "\" denotes pre-multiplication by the inverse of the first factor, C'+C".

I hope this helps.

[I apologize for the poor formatting here.  Stack Overflow has inferred that the algebraic expressions are code, and demanded formatting them as code before it would let me answer.  They aren't, so I couldn't.]